# How to stimulate more creative storytelling?

Tags: house-rules, rorys-story-cubes

According to the blurb on the box,

> [Rory's Story Cubes<sup>®</sup>](https://www.storycubes.com/) is a pocket-sized visual story generator that sparks the imagination of all ages.

[image: Story Cubes]

You throw 9 dice and then create a story that connects the images shown on the dice.

However, when I play with my kids, the game often devolves into "connect the dots as fast as possible", for example:

> There once was a (first cube), who met a (next cube), and then he saw a (next cube), then he went to the (next cube), and so on.

What can I do to help us get away from this type of storytelling and become more creative with our stories? Are there any house rules I can add to discourage or prevent the "and then, and then, and then" storytelling?

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best place to get an answer to this question. Your question is related to a dice game, but the core problem you are facing is about writing/telling a good story from a prompt. I would suggest checking [Writers.StackExchange](http://writers.stackexchange.com/), but if you do you should check their rules to see if this would be on topic.

Comment: Well yes, the whole _point_ of the game is telling a story. And creativity can be an important part of a game (for instance the more RPG-like games).

Comment: You want help with storytelling. The storytelling is happening in the context of a board game, but that does not mean that you are going to get a better answer on a site about board games than on a site about storytelling.

Comment: Well, not exactly. In looking for mechanisms that will enable our stimulate more creative storytelling. Perhaps additional (house) rules, like "you need to use at least 4 lines per die".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a number of "[ways to play](https://www.storycubes.com/play)" on the Story Cubes website. Some just involve getting more or other dice and are little more then showcases or advertisements for different sets, but others are actually house rules, or alternate rules. I will be trying those out.

#### #4 Superheroes

Each person roles 3 cubes and uses these to create a superhero (superpowers and a name). Then all 9 cubes are rolled by each to create a back story for their superhero. Finally, all 9 cubes are rolled again to create an arch-nemesis, as a group.
Now we're set to play. Cubes are rolled as usual to create exciting adventures pitting the heroes against their enemy.

#### #1 Roll & Play

Also, while roll & play is the standard way of playing, it showed the icons on the dice do not need to be interpreted as literally as we were doing. No additional rules, but another way of using the existing rules.

---

<sup>I initially thought they were all just advertisements for different sets of cubes, but some of them offer the kind of additions to the rules I was looking for.

 

Of course, other ideas are still welcome.</sup>